# Synchronize animations in different browser windows

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions, smil

I'm working on an app which will display a kind of animated slideshow. Multiple monitors will be showing different, but related animations, controlled by the same computer.

Animations must be synchronized across different monitors. That is, on monitor A, an element will start moving, and on monitor B, a completely different element will start moving, and these must happen at apparently the same time.

My assumption is that we will use a different browser window for each monitor.

It was easy to use timeouts to get the animations to fire at the same moment - I compare current Time to a scheduled time, and wait for that number of milliseconds. A console.log() at the top of the method shows that both methods fire within 1 or 2 milliseconds of each other. But, the animations don't occur at the same time. Eyeballing it, one lags the other by as much as a third of a second. It's not consistent which one is first and which is last. (FYI these are CSS3 animations.)

So, if setTimeout won't do it, what other options are there?

Should I move to SVG/SMIL? We get to choose which browser we are running.

Or, is the simple solution to have a browser window span all the monitors?

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely have your browser window span all of the monitors. That way, all your animations operate on the same thread and you can time everything just right. Having two different browser windows would make timings a nightmare. Even if the CSS is a little trickier due to the very wide window, you are better off in the long run IMHO.

Depending on what types of CSS3 animations you will be doing, you could go with a framework such as [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) that handles the CSS3 animations for you rather easily. Here is an example:

```
//Fire off 1st and 4th object simultaneously
$("#object1, #object4").transition({ "y": 300 }, 5000, "in",function () {

    //Fire off 2nd/3rd object once 1st/4th have finished their thing
    $("#object2, #object3").transition({ "y": 500, "background-color": "red" });
});
```

### [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uZbNd/)